# Adding a Slanted overlay on-top of an image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an portfolio for a friend - one of the requests is that he has a splash screen image that has a diagonal box going across an image- this is where id then place some text. I created a moc-up of what I'm trying to say however I cannot figure out how to code it, I'm using HTML CSS and JS so I can do what ever..

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="name">
        <div class="transbox1">
    <img src="Assets/Background.png" class="bg1 color_overlay">
            <h1>John</h1>
            <h2>Doe</h2>
        </div>


/*CSS*/
    .bg1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -5% !important;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 70%, 0 70%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 70%, 0 70%);   
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.transbox1 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;

}
```

[The Mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7oJg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```js
window.onload = function() {

var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
var width = image.offsetWidth;
var height = image.offsetHeight;

var triangle = document.getElementsByClassName('triangle')[0];
triangle.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
triangle.style.borderWidth = '0 0 ' + height + 'px ' + width + 'px';
triangle.style.borderColor = 'transparent transparent #007bff transparent';

}
```

```css
.container {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:200px;
}

.image { 
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


.triangle {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:0px;
width:0px;
display:inline-block;
}

.title {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 right:10px;
 font-size:34px;
 font-family:helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Polarlicht_2.jpg/2560px-Polarlicht_2.jpg" class="image">

    <div class="triangle"></div>
    
    <div class="title">FName <br> LName</div>

</div>
```

Comment: How would I then add the Client Name into the bottom right corner? Could I use a <h1> with padding or would I have to do something different?

Comment: I would place the image, the triangle, and then a separate <div> containing the h1 into a single div, and then use positioning (like I have done to place the triangle on top of the image) to place the text where you want it!

Comment: I have edited the above code to reflect what I mean!

Comment: I added your code but when I do I just end up with a site that looks like [link](https://i.imgur.com/XtUBhD6.png)

Comment: [Here you go](https://i.imgur.com/Rn7IXgh.png)

I Litterally just Copyed and pasted your code, but not getting the same result, I even tried putting the .js internally but ended up with the same thing

Comment: hmm that's odd, I've just double checked and when I stick that code into a blank document and open it in my browser it's working fine, you don't happen to have any other items with the same class names do you? If so you would have to change the class names I've used!

Answer (score 0):

I added `position:relative` to the container and cleaned up your markup and it works okay:

```css
/*CSS*/

.name {
  position: relative;
}

.bg1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

.transbox1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div class="name">
  <div class="transbox1">
    <img src="Assets/Background.png" class="bg1 color_overlay">
    <h1>John</h1>
    <h2>Doe</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```